# UE4 C++ Multiple widgets created for the same actor in UI

Tags: c++, user-interface, widget, unreal-engine4

I am trying to set up a system that displays the ground loot near the player (i.e., actors that are overlapping the player's UBoxComponent). This needs to change as and when the player moves and the ground loot actors are no longer being overlapped.

I have sort of got it working - when the actors are on their own the function seems to work. However, when two ground loot actors are close to one another, the inventory displays multiple widgets for the same overlapping actor on the floor and sometimes only recognises one of the actors on the floor. It seems to be having trouble when the Player's UBoxComponent overlaps more than one actor at a time. I'll link a YouTube video to help show the issue I'm having because it's quite hard to describe: https://youtu.be/a_zMl1zOUDc

This is the function for updating the ground loot widgets. It is called by a dynamic multicast delegate that is broadcasted from the player class:

```
// Iterates through the ground loot around the player and displays a widget for each item
void UInventory::UpdateGroundLoot()
    {
        MyPlayer = Cast<AMainCharacter>(GetOwningPlayer()->GetCharacter());
        
        if(!MyPlayer) { return; } // Null check
        
        // Get a ref to the Player's inventory component
        UInventoryComponent* PlayerInventoryComp = MyPlayer->PlayerInventory;
        
        // Clear any current widgets in the ground loot list
        GroundLootScrollBox->ClearChildren();
        
        // GroundLootActorsArray is an array of AActors that gets added to/emptied based on AActors that overlap with the Player's UBoxComponent
        if(!PlayerInventoryComp && !PlayerInventoryComp->GroundLootActorsArray.IsValidIndex(0)) { return; } // Null check
        
        for(int32 i = 0; i < PlayerInventoryComp->GroundLootActorsArray.Num(); i++)
        {
            // Cast each element of the GroundLootItems array to AItem* GroundItem
            AItem* GroundItem = Cast<AItem>(PlayerInventoryComp->GroundLootActorsArray[i]);
            
            if(!GroundItem) { return; } // Null check
            
            // Add GroundItem to a new array (GroundLootItemsArray). This is an array specifically of AItems (rather than AActors).
            GroundLootItemsArray.Add(GroundItem);
            
            GroundLootWidget = CreateWidget<UInventoryItemWidget>(GetOwningPlayer(), InventoryItemWidgetClass);
            
            // Add each created widget to an array of widgets called GroundLootWidgetsArray
            GroundLootWidgetsArray.Add(GroundLootWidget);
            
            if(!GroundLootWidgetsArray.IsValidIndex(0) && !GroundLootItemsArray.IsValidIndex(0)) { return; } // Null check
            
            // Display item specific names/thumbnails for each widget created
            GroundLootWidgetsArray[i]->ItemName->SetText(GroundLootItemsArray[i]->ItemDisplayName);
            GroundLootWidgetsArray[i]->Thumbnail->SetBrushFromTexture(GroundLootItemsArray[i]->Thumbnail);
            
            // Add each array element of the GroundLootWidgetsArray to the scroll box in the widget blueprint
            GroundLootScrollBox->AddChild(GroundLootWidgetsArray[i]);       
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Looks to me that code is doing exactly what your asking it to do.

This seems more an issue that however your adding the Actors to the `GroundLootActorsArray` isnt working correctly.

Comment: Thanks. You were right! I've just looked at the TriggerEnter and TriggerExit functions that are called by the `OnComponentBeginOverlap` and the `OnComponentEndOverlap` delegate and I have updated their logic which fixed half of it. I also needed to empty the array of AItems when I clear the children of the `WeaponScrollBox`. I will post the answer with code to explain what I did more clearly for anyone who might come across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevilsD in the comments pointed me in the right direction here. There were two main issues I had.

1. The delegate that was designed to update the ground loot widgets was being broadcasted in a `for loop` for every element of the `OverlappingActor` array. I think this resulted in multiple widgets being displayed for the same actor. The code in the Player's class now looks like this (`TriggerEnter` and `TriggerExit` are called by the `OnComponentBeginOverlap` and `OnComponentEndOverlap` delegates in the constructor respectively) :

```
    void AMainCharacter::TriggerEnter(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor,
        UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
    {
        bItemIsWithinRange = true;
        
        // I think the TSubclassOf ensures that we only pickup AItem classes and it's children - rather than all actors on the ground
        OverlappedComponent->GetOverlappingActors(OverlappingActors, TSubclassOf<AItem>(AItem::StaticClass()));
    
        if(PlayerInventory && OverlappingActors.IsValidIndex(0))
        {
            for(auto& GroundItems : OverlappingActors)
            {
                PlayerInventory->AddItemToGroundLoot(GroundItems);
            }
            OnUpdateGroundLoot.Broadcast();
        }
    }

    void AMainCharacter::TriggerExit(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor,
        UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex)
    {
        bItemIsWithinRange = false;
    
        if(PlayerInventory && OverlappingActors.IsValidIndex(0))
        {
            for(auto& GroundItems : OverlappingActors)
            {
                PlayerInventory->GroundLootActorsArray.Remove(GroundItems);
            }
            OnUpdateGroundLoot.Broadcast();
            OverlappingActors.Empty();
        }
    }
```

2. I wasn't emptying the `GroundLootItemsArray` every time I was updating the ground loot and so previous ground loot was being stored in this array on each new update. This also resulted in showing the same widget for two different actors. I have now set it to empty along with clearing the children of the scroll box before any widget creation takes place in the UInventory.cpp (which is a child of UUserWidget):

```
// Iterates through the ground loot around the player and displays a widget for each item
void UInventory::UpdateGroundLoot()
{
    MyPlayer = Cast<AMainCharacter>(GetOwningPlayer()->GetCharacter());
    
    if(!MyPlayer) { return; } // Null check
    
    // Get a ref to the Player's inventory component
    UInventoryComponent* PlayerInventoryComp = MyPlayer->PlayerInventory;
    
    // Clear any current widgets in the ground loot list
    GroundLootScrollBox->ClearChildren();
    // Empties this array to prevent replication of Item specific information that gets sent to the widget (i.e., the thumbnail or the name of the item)
    GroundLootItemsArray.Empty();
    
    // GroundLootActorsArray is an array of AActors that gets added to/emptied based on AActors that overlap with the Player's UBoxComponent
    if(!PlayerInventoryComp && !PlayerInventoryComp->GroundLootActorsArray.IsValidIndex(0)) { return; } // Null check
    
    for(int32 i = 0; i < PlayerInventoryComp->GroundLootActorsArray.Num(); i++)
    {
        // Cast each element of the GroundLootItems array to AItem* GroundItem
        AItem* GroundItem = Cast<AItem>(PlayerInventoryComp->GroundLootActorsArray[i]);
        
        if(!GroundItem) { return; } // Null check
        
        // Add GroundItem to a new array (GroundLootItemsArray). This is an array specifically of AItems (rather than AActors).
        GroundLootItemsArray.AddUnique(GroundItem);
        
        GroundLootWidget = CreateWidget<UInventoryItemWidget>(GetOwningPlayer(), InventoryItemWidgetClass);
        
        // Add each created widget to an array of widgets called GroundLootWidgetsArray
        GroundLootWidgetsArray.AddUnique(GroundLootWidget);
        
        if(!GroundLootWidgetsArray.IsValidIndex(0) && !GroundLootItemsArray.IsValidIndex(0)) { return; } // Null check
        
        // Display item specific names/thumbnails for each widget created
        GroundLootWidgetsArray[i]->ItemName->SetText(GroundLootItemsArray[i]->ItemDisplayName);
        GroundLootWidgetsArray[i]->Thumbnail->SetBrushFromTexture(GroundLootItemsArray[i]->Thumbnail);
        
        // Add each array element of the GroundLootWidgetsArray to the scroll box in the widget blueprint
        GroundLootScrollBox->AddChild(GroundLootWidgetsArray[i]);       
    }   
}
```

I also changed the adding of actors/items to the arrays from `Array.Add(Actor)` to `Array.AddUnique(Actor)`. I'm not sure if this was necessary but it made sense to me because I didn't want more than one of any given item accidently being added to the array.